# How to handle additional columns in test data that are not in Train data

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction

I have been developing a model using Random Forest.My Train data set has 15 columns lets say A to O. The model is trained using the aforementioned features. Assumed that Test set will also have the same number of features or Columns.But now client has added few columns and the Model failed to predict for the new data..It is applicable for both Regression and classification problem.

Is there any way / mechanism to handle or Avoid the newly added columns besides what is available in Train ? Do we have to write a code explicitly or any parameters / Build-in functions available to handle such scenario. Appreciate your help. Thanks !

Comment: You should just create a subset of the data which includes only the columns you trained on or create an equation within the ml method call that identifies your columns of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just keep a list of columns from train data and use columns only from this list for test data.

Comment: Sure..That was my plan as well.. Rather than going for explicit programing looking for a function or package which ease the work.Because ,In future we may have to add few of the new columns into Train and revisit the model. In such cases , every time, we have to change the code..  Initially i thought it could be complex to customize ..now got an idea. Thanks